# How do I make Playonlinux convince MS Office I'm running win 10 or higher?

Tags: linux-mint, playonlinux, microsoft-word

Okay, so I recently installed linux Mint and I'm trying to install Microsoft Office 2016. I try the solution witn Play on Linux. First I ran into some problems (PoL couldn't finish the download) but I fixed that by putting the .exe-file into the PoL "Ressources"-folder.

That seemed to allow PoL to download the file and to install MS Office, however I then ran into a new problem. MS Office generated the following message:

[image]

.....And after that PoL generated its own error message, claiming that something might be wrong with the program.

How do I fix this? Can I somehow make PoL convince the office file that Iäm actually running Windows 10 or higher?

I'm aware that there are other threads discussing the installation on office on linux, but I didn't see any of them addressing this particular error message.

If this stackexchange does not accept this kind of questions then please point me to somewhere that does. Stackoverflow apparantly does not, and askubuntu regards questions dealing exclusively with Linux Mint as Off-topic.....

Comment: Do you need `Office 2016`? Because below versions could work better (I've tested time ago Office 2013 and I had problems so I used Office 2010 instead). Maybe running Office 2016 under [Crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/crossover) could work (but you have to pay, or test it during 14 free days)

Comment: I have legal licences for windows 2013, 2016 and 2019, I'd prefer not having to buy the 2010 version as well (if this is at all possible). I already tried with crossover, I managed to start the program but got an error immediatly ("an error has occured that will force office to shut down, do you wish to repair?"). It also complains about the program being unlicenced which is quite strange. Codeweavers recommend fixing this error by installing IE 8 in the bottle (does not work). Microsoft recommends fixing this error by deleting windows registry files (hard on linux).

Comment: And I "did" try installning the 2016 version on my windows system, it seems to work fine so I don't think the fault lies with the .exe-file (it said it would change to the 2016 version but it still displays "2019" so i might be wrong though).

Comment: Did you already try using `regedit`? I'm not sure how PlayOnLinux works. I think it takes the wine installation from the system. Try running `regedit` in your terminal or run `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/regedit.exe`. When the app opens go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` -> `Software` -> `Microsoft` -> `Windows NT` -> `Current Version`. When you make click on the last one you should see `ProductName` (in the right panel). Check the value of `ProductName` (in my case shows: Microsoft Windows 10). I've never managed wine so I'm not sure if this will work or makes any sense.

Comment: It says microsoft windows 7.....

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I typed "sudo apt install wine" into my terminal but it said it was already the latest version ^^

Comment: Regarding `microsoft windows 7` change it to `Microsoft Windows 10`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Maybe you have an old system and for that reason the windows version is set to windows 7 (since wine is already updated than the problem might be the system, thus you should change de value in the registry. Perhaps that works)

Comment: What does "system" mean in this case? I'm runing Linux mint 21.1, kernel version 5.15-0.57 generic

Comment: Operating system, but I see that's irrelevant now. You have an updated system. I'm not sure why wine registry show Microsoft windows 7 instead of Microsoft windows 10.

Comment: Also I changed the value in regedit to Microsoft Windows 10. Office still gives the same error message (maybe I need to change the ProductID or something else?)

Comment: I don't think so (maybe the product is unique). Try now this: 1) Run `winecfg` 2) When the GUI opens select (maybe it's selected by default) the tab `Applications` 3) In the combobox `Windows Version` select `Windows 10`

Comment: Done and done. Same exact error. Restarted the computer in betweein tries just in case. Cheked the winecfg after reboot and the windows version still said Windows 10. Still the same error ^^

Comment: Hope this helps: 1) Make you are installing a 64 bits version of Office 2016. 2) Check the requirements in [this site, in Test Results -> Workarounds](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33762)